# Using JIRA Agile for Scrum (from a Rally user background)

Tags: jira, rally, agile-project-management

I have been using Rally for Project Management in my previous organization, and now I have to use Jira Agile for the same job in the new organization. I am having hard time understanding the way JIRA Agile works, and could not get a hang of the tool after a week of struggle. I am sorting expert help for what I would like to achieve. I have been using JIRA for many years as a bug logging tool but not as project management software.

All I want is to create an Epics and Stories, schedule it into a particular release or sprint. On Rally this is straight forward. Few images attached here.
[image: AT a glance story information]
[image: Tasks in the story, and estimation]
[image: Scrum Board]

I could also see the burn-down once I do the above setup, and the developers/qa start burning down or burning up the hours.

I could not achieve the same on JIRA. It asks me to create a scrum board, but I don't have  a clue on how to add the child tasks to a story without creating a new child task (which I don't prefer as the tasks were already created and few started progressing).

The scrum board is also not the way it is on Rally, as it does not list the stories but directly shows the tasks which I am unable to correlate with the story. Can any one point me to a proper tutorial or assist me based on your experience in JIRA? Thank you in advance.

Comment: What was it about this tutorial you didn't like? https://confluence.atlassian.com/plugins/servlet/mobile#content/view/391087260

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend two things that might make it a bit more easier for you to transition from how you structured your projects before: the Jira plugin "Structure" and using epics, stories and sub-tasks in a defined and controlled manner.

About the plugin: Structure allows you to define a structure, a container that may even span multiple projects, and lets you put issues in. Secondly, and more important, it allows to create any number of sub-task levels. You can use the structure view to show and hide sub-levels, or if you use the agile boards you can just apply a quick filter to the board.

The same goes for using epics, stories and sub-tasks, just make sure everyone able to enter issues follows the same criteria and then add some filters.

Hope this helps a bit

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/AGILE/JIRA+Agile+101 - it should cover most of the basics to get you going.